# Maps Implementation Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, joomla3.0

I am having an issue with a Map embed that seems to only be happening on the dev server and only using this template. I have spent two days trying to diagnose the issue to no avail.

Here is the dev page: http://209.59.161.55/~atbencold/locations-hours/maryland/annopolis-area/1918-west-pike-st.html

The map seems to be functioning just fine, however in the Chrome inspector I am seeing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
at Object._.vg (js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBWGD9vRktGaqGHBjkg-rSUyjkj7ReOwQk&language=en:85)
at new Ag (js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBWGD9vRktGaqGHBjkg-rSUyjkj7ReOwQk&language=en:87)
at initialize80_1200188964 (1918-west-pike-st.html:531)
```

My research shows this issue happening when when the map is not functioning at all. Can anyone provide any assistance as my Javascript knowledge is not very strong.

Comment: Or even if someone could give any recommendations for what to check into, that may even be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, jQuery is loading before Google Maps and MooTools.

These three libraries seem to work best together when MooTools loads first, then jQuery and then Google Maps last.

You might be able to force MooTools to load first by adding this line high up in the HEAD section of the template `index.php` file:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.framework', true);
```

[jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy) can also help with loading the libraries in the right order and may be able to help with stopping MooTools loading if it is not needed.

Comment: Do you mean to add it to the Template index.php or in the root index.php? I have not seen any changes when adding that line to either one.

Comment: My suggestion is for the template index.php file but if this does not work, it might be best to try jQuery Easy.

Comment: ok thank you, I will play with it and see what I can come up with.